# OpenCV's imencode gives wrong output for .jpg

Tags: c++, windows, opencv

I'm trying to generate a text representation of the corresponding image file (**.jpg** **.png**) from cv::Mat. For this task there is a function [`imencode`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga461f9ac09887e47797a54567df3b8b63), which in my case works well for generating **.bmp**, **.ppm**, **.ras** files. However, when I try to generate a **.jpg** or **.png** file, I get an incorrect image. In the case of **PNG**, I get a file that I can't even open.
With the following code

```
cv::Mat image, temp;
std::vector<uchar> file;
std::ofstream fout("result.jpg");

image = cv::imread("origin.jpg");

temp = image;
// image.convertTo(converted_image, CV_16U);  I tried this as well
cv::imencode(".jpg", temp , file);
std::copy(file.begin(), file.end(), std::ostream_iterator<uchar>(fout, ""));
```

So with such [origin.jpg](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/844818758227853352/867770205266247710/image.jpg)

[image]

I get the following [result.jpg](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/844818758227853352/867770283707203636/result.jpg), which is not nearly desirable

[image]

Comment: First thing to try is opening the output file in binary mode: `std::ofstream fout("result.jpg", std::ios::binary);`

Comment: and no, you can't compare pictures like that. if a single pixel differs somehow, the "strings" will be different.